# why do we used dual space $g ?$

Tags: functional-analysis

let $X$  and $Y$ be normed spaces , $T \in B(X,Y)$ and  $(x_n)$ a sequence in $X$. If $x_n \overset{w}{\rightarrow} x$ .Show that  $Tx_n \overset{w}{\rightarrow} Tx$

My attempt : I found the answer [here](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Ewick/teaching/math6338/math6338_hw4.pdf)

In the begining of the proof   it is written that we need to show that  $ g(T_nx) \to g(T x) ,g \in Y*$

Im   not geting why do  we used dual space $g $? In question dual space is not mention

Comment: What do you think $\stackrel{w}\to$ means?

Comment: it is "mentioned" in the question, when you talk about the weak topology

Comment: @EricWofsey weakly convergence

Comment: Yes, and this is what weak convergence means.

Comment: @Ian weak limit $x$ of $(x_n )$ is unique

Comment: @jasmine how do you define weak convergence then?

Comment: Ok, I get it now ,A  sequence $(x_n) $in normed space $X $is said to be weakly convergent if there is an $x \in X$ such that for every$ f \in X$' , $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$